# Can someone explain what these messages are REALLY telling me?

Tags: init, modem-manager, virtual-terminal

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uqRyL.jpg]

Trying to log back in, init greets with messages like `Failed to spawn encryptfs-utils-save` (I don't care for encryption and my drives are never encrypted....at least, not by me - so who or what is encrypting [or trying to] and how can I stop this unathorised encrypting occurring on my hard drives?).

`Failed to spawn plymouth-upstart-bridge main process - unable to execute - no such file or directory`

5 virtual terminals I wasn't aware of (at the time) killed as well. Perhaps a good thing?

`irqbalance main process killed` (isn't that for RAID? I have no need for virtualisation and hold RAID in mild contempt for it's monumental security exploitabilities)

`modem-manager[993] - caught signal 15, shutting down...` (seriously? I'm assuming that has nothing to do with my PPPoE connection, does it?)

`dbus main process (856) killed` - (I'm a little hazy on the dbus - and suspicious of what it's primarily used for - at least, on my machines which are full of Perl and Python and Ruby and endless catastrophic system failures)

Can anyone shed some light on any of these, or - if I'm lucky - all of them?

Comment: is this the same disc: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57963/18-billion-gb-extended-partition-showing-in-gparted-how-was-this-done
if so ...  fix your disc and the errors will be gone. The encryption warning is mostlikely triggered by the partition errors it found in your other topic.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

`init: Failed to spawn hwclock main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory` will show up when your disc is seriously messed up.

I found 2 ways of getting this to happen:

1. When you use `rm -r` in your root directory and then reboot.
2. A broken disc/partition table.

The 1st is solved by re-installing. The 2nd might not be solvable; formatting from a live cd with gparted might answer this.

Either way... if you need to rescue files from the system I advice starting up a live cd and backup them up first.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind! I believe your answer might well be spot on, although I'm not sure about the reinstallation solution for (1) as this screenshot was the result of an attempt to reinstall following an ill-advised but necessary rm -fr attack on a corrupted root filesystem. I would vote up but I don't know how to get points ;(